# install CoreOSon VMware Fusion

Tags: coreos, vmware-fusion

I'm trying to install CoreOS on VMware Fusion.I follow the steps on official guide,but when I append "coreos.autologin" to the kernel parameters on boot,it showed error: cannot find the command 'load_coreos' ? 
So,what could I do ?

Comment: eee... nobody knows ?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you're probably hitting a bug.
You might try one of the [Primary Methods documented for configuring CoreOS on vmWare](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/booting-on-vmware.html) using Cloud Config parameters.  This is the primary documented method for accessing a CoreOS system remotely, and uses password-less login using ssh keys.

1. using [Cloud Config](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/booting-on-vmware.html) on a [config-drive](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-cloudinit/blob/master/Documentation/config-drive.md)
2. [use the vmWare Guestinfo interface](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/booting-on-vmware.html#vmware-guestinfo-interface) to set Cloud Config Parameters

Whichever you choose, you should at least configure the `ssh_authorized_keys` Cloud Config parameter. This is the ssh key that will be used to log in to the CoreOS system as the **core** user.

Answer (score 0):

try following line instead of the load_coreos command :

```
linux$suf /coreos/vmlinuz-a mount.usr=PARTUUID=$usr_uuid coreos.autologin
```